# Does node js execute multiple commands in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Does node js execute multiple commands in parallel or execute one command (and finish it!) and then execute the second command?

**For example if multiple async functions use the same Stack, and they push & pop "together", can I get strange behaviour?**

Comment: What do you mean by "command"?

Comment: If you define your functions as promises, yes they can run in "parallel", remembering you that node.js is a single-threaded runtime

Comment: "command" = "line of code" E.G: stack.push(18);

Answer (score 2):

Node.js runs your main Javascript (excluding manually created Worker Threads for now) as a single thread.  So, it's only ever executing one piece of your Javascript at a time.

But, when a server request contains asynchronous operations, what happens in that request handle is that it starts the asynchronous operation and then returns control back to the interpreter.   The asynchronous operation runs on its own (usually in native code).  While all that is happening, the JS interpreter is free to go back to the event loop and pick up the next event waiting to be run.  If that's another incoming request for your server, it will grab that request and start running it.  When it hits an asynchronous operation and returns back to the interpreter, the interpreter then goes back to the event loop for the next event waiting to run.  That could either be another incoming request or it could be one of the previous asynchronous operations that is now ready to run it's callback.

In this way, node.js makes forward progress on multiple requests at a time that involve asynchronous operations (such as networking, database requests, file system operations, etc...) while only ever running one piece of your Javascript at a time.

Starting with node v10.5, nodejs has Worker Threads.  These are not automatically used by the system yet in normal service of networking requests, but you can create your own Worker Threads and run some amount of Javascript in a truly parallel thread.  This probably isn't need for code that is primarily I/O bound because the asynchronous nature of I/O in Javascript already gives it plenty of parallelism.  But, if you had CPU-intensive operations (heavy crypto, image analysis, video compression, etc... that was done in Javascript), Worker Threads may definitely be worth adding for those particular tasks.

To show you an example, let's look at two request handlers, one that reads a file from disk and one that fetches some data from a network endpoint.

```
 app.get("/getFileData", (req, res) => {
      fs.readFile("myFile.html", function(err, html) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             res.sendStatus(500);
         } else {
             res.type('html').send(html);
         }
      })
 });

 app.get("/getNetworkData", (req, res) => {
     got("http://somesite.com/somepath").then(result => {
         res.json(result);
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.sendStatus(500);
     });
 });
```

In the `/getFileData` request, here's the sequence of events:

1. Client sends request for `http://somesite.com/getFileData`
2. Incoming network event is processed by the OS
3. When node.js gets to the event loop, it sees an event for an incoming TCP connection on the port its http server is listening for and calls a callback to process that request
4. The http library in node.js gets that request, parses it, and notifies the observes of that request, once of which will be the Express framework
5. The Express framework matches up that request with the above request handler and calls the request handler
6. That request handler starts to execute and calls `fs.readFile("myfile.html", ...)`.  Because that is asynchronous, calling the function just initiates the process (carrying out the first steps), registers its completion callback and then it immediately returns.
7. At this point, you can see from that `/getFileData` request handler that after it calls `fs.readFile()`, the request handler just returns.  Until the callback is called, it has nothing else to do.
8. This returns control back to the nodejs event loop where nodejs can pick out the next event waiting to run and execute it.

In the `/getNetworkData` request, here's the sequence of events

Steps 1-5 are the same as above.
6. The request handler starts to execute and calls `got("http://somesite.com/somepath")`.  That initiates a request to that endpoint and then immediately returns a promise.  Then, the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers are registered to monitor that promise.
7. At this point, you can see from that `/getNetworkData` request handler that after it calls `got().then().catch()`, the request handler just returns.  Until the promise is resolved or rejected, it has nothing else to do.
8. This returns control back to the nodejs event loop where nodejs can pick out the next event waiting to run and execute it.

Now, sometime in the future, `fs.readFile("myFile.html", ...)` completes.  At this point, some internal sub-system (that may use other native code threads) inserts a completion event in the node.js event loop.

When node.js gets back to the event loop, it will see that event and run the completion callback associated with the `fs.readFile()` operation.  That will trigger the rest of the logic in that request handler to run.

Then, sometime in the future the network request from `got("http://somesite.com/somepath")` will complete and that will trigger an event in the event loop to call the completion callback for that network operation.  That callback will resolve or reject the promise which will trigger the `.then()` or `.catch()` callbacks to be called and the second request will execute the rest of its logic.

---

Hopefully, you can see from these examples how request handlers initiate an asynchronous operation, then return control back to the interpreter where the interpreter can then pull the next event from the event loop and run it.  Then, as asynchronous operations complete, other things are inserted into the event loop causing further progress to run on each request handler until eventually they are done with their work.  So, multiple sections of code can be making progress without more than one piece of code every running at the same time.  It's essentially cooperative multi-tasking where the time slicing between operations occurs at the boundaries of asynchronous operations, rather than an automatic pre-emptive time slicing in a fully threaded system.

Nodejs gets a number of advantages from this type of multi-tasking as it's a lot, lot lower overhead (cooperative task switching is a lot more efficient than time-sliced automatic task switching) and it also doesn't have most of the usual thread synchronization issues that true multi-threaded systems do which can make them a lot more complicated to code and/or more prone to difficult bugs.